# Is it possible to display an extension in the dropdown menu of team explorer

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-sdk

For my team explorer extension I would like to display it in the drop down menu of team explorer. If a page of my extension is showing it shows up in the menu, but if the page isn't displaying it doesn't show. The drop down menu I am referring to is the one one you click at the top of the team explorer page where you can switch to different pages such as Changes, Branches, and Sync. Is this even possible? If so does anyone have an example or link?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug of VS 2015. I am using 2 add-ins in VS 2015 which were both displayed in the VS 2013 team explorer drop down menu. After porting them to VS 2015 that does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding the TargetPageId parameter to the TeamExplorerNavigationItem attribute on the NavigationItem that launches the page does the trick.